# property of separable Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

how to prove:

If $X$ is a separable Banach space, then there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 0}\subset X^*$ such that
$$\|x\|=\sup_n |f_n(x)|$$
for all $x\in X$

---

I don't know how to deal with "separable" since it is a property of $X$, not $X^*$, any hints would be appreciate!

---

Thanks to Daniel's comment:

Let $\Lambda$ be the unit sphere of $X^*$, then $\forall f\in\Lambda$
$$|f(x)|\le \|f\|_{X^*}\|x\|=\|x\|$$
hence $\sup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}|f_\alpha(x)|\le \|x\|$
consider $f(x)=\|x\|$, we have $\sup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}|f_\alpha(x)|= \|x\|$.

finally by the weak* separability of $\Lambda$, we can find a sequence s.t.
$$\sup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}|f_\alpha(x)|=\sup_n|f_n(x)|$$

Comment: The separability of $X$ implies the weak$^{\ast}$-separability of the closed unit ball of $X^{\ast}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot.

Comment: $X$ is separable : it has a basis $\{e_k\}$. For each $e_k$, find a sequence $\{g_{m}(k)\}_m \subset X^*,\|g_{m}(k)\| = 1$ such that $\sup_m |g_{m}(k)(e_k)| = \|e_k\|$, and build $f_n$ from this.